# Using the BitBucket 2.0 API, how can I query commits from a specific user/author?

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-api

I'm looking to fetch all repo commits from a specific user/author and I can't quite get my head around the [filtering documentation from Atlassian](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/bitbucket/rest/intro/#filtering).

Entering this in my browser *(with the placeholders changed for my project)* lists out 30 items from my project.

`https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/{workspace}/{repo_slug}/commits`

But I want it to list out only the commits authored by myself. I've tried all sorts or variations like:

`.../commits?q=reviewers.nickname+"marknotton"`

`.../commits?q=user+%3D+"marknotton"`

`.../commits?author="marknotton"`

Every variations just returns the same results. My url params are ignored, presumably because they are invalid. This could just be a silly syntax issue? Are there any examples I could refer to for help?

Answer (score 0):

The following API can get you the commits in a repo by a specific user:

```
https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/{owner}/{repo_slug}/commits?exclude_replies=true&fields=values.hash,values.date,values.message,values.author.user.username&username={username}
```

It was not mentioned properly in the document so I did some hit and trial to reach this url.

Answer (score -3):

```
https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/{workspace}/{repo_slug}/commits?state=merged&username.1=marknotton&role.1=AUTHOR
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.